# Draw rectangle C# Mouse_down working Mouse_up not

Tags: c#, forms, draw, rectangles

I want to draw an rectangle on an form the mouse_down event is working fine, but how do i programm the mouse_up. Should how do i dertermine the starting coordinates.

http://oi49.tinypic.com/2wcnof8.jpg

```
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    Color rastercolor = Color.Black;

    private void drawGrid(Color rastercolor)
    {
        Graphics gfx = this.CreateGraphics();
        Pen pen = new Pen(rastercolor);
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2000; i = i + 20)
        {
            gfx.DrawLine(pen, 0, i, 2000, i);
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < 2000; x = x + 20)
        {
            gfx.DrawLine(pen, x, 0, x, 2000);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        rect = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
        {
            ColorDialog coldial = new ColorDialog();
            coldial.ShowDialog();
            Color rastercolor = coldial.Color;
            tekenGrid(rastercolor);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            rect = new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, e.X - rect.Left, e.Y - rect.Top);
        }
    }


    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        tekenGrid(rastercolor);
        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
        }
    }

    private void Frm1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
    }

    private void Frm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Frm1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2);
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
    }
}
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: Is the `Mouse_Up` event not executed?

Comment: I know but i am stuck at the coordinates i have to define

Comment: You could always use `Control.MousePosition` to determin the current mouse position. But I really dont see why you need it. In you `mouse_up` event you can extract the loction of the `rect` Rectangle by using `rect.Location`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are upto. Please try this code.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
    }

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(); 
       Color _rastercolor = Color.Black;
       private Pen _pen=new Pen(Color.Red,2);

        private void tekenGrid(Color rastercolor,  Graphics gfx)
        {

            Pen pen = new Pen(rastercolor);
            for (int i = 0; i <= 2000; i = i + 20)
            {
                gfx.DrawLine(pen, 0, i, 2000, i);
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < 2000; x = x + 20)
            {
                gfx.DrawLine(pen, x, 0, x, 2000);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            rect = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Middle)
            {
                ColorDialog coldial = new ColorDialog();
                coldial.ShowDialog();
                Color rastercolor = coldial.Color;
                tekenGrid(rastercolor,this.CreateGraphics());
            }
            else
            base.OnMouseDown(e);
        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                rect = new Rectangle(rect.Left, rect.Top, e.X - rect.Left, e.Y - rect.Top);
                this.Refresh();
            }

            base.OnMouseMove(e);
        }


        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            tekenGrid(_rastercolor,e.Graphics);
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(_pen, rect);
        }

        private void Frm1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            _pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2);
            this.Refresh();
        }

        private void Frm1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Frm1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
           _pen = new Pen(Color.Blue, 2);

        }

}
```

Comment: Thanxs for answering, but this is not what need. it is drawing a red/blue rectangle on the same place. 'OnMouseDown' i want to draw an blue rectangle and on 'OnMouseUp'and red rectangle each time I move the mouse over the form, so also save the already drawn rectangles.

Comment: You should maintain a collection of rectangles in that case. And then, replace the Draw methods with a loop.

Comment: You can also maintain a `Dictionary<Rectangle,Pen>` if you want multi-coloured rectangles. be warned, If blue/red rectangles are at same position, you will see only one.